# Need if statement to check for null UDF SQL server

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions

I have a function to get length of service I need to do a if statement to check on blank dates 
am i able to use the term   if @DateLeftOrg == '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
 what i need to do is if @DateLeftOrg is null to use GETDATE() otherwise I use the value from @DateLeftoRG

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[hmsGetLosText]
    (@FromDt as datetime,@DateLeftOrg as Datetime) 
returns varchar(255)
as
BEGIN
    DECLARE @yy AS SMALLINT, @mm AS INT, @dd AS INT,
            @getmm as INT, @getdd as INT, @Fvalue varchar(255)


    SET @yy = DATEDIFF(yy, @FromDt, GETDATE())
    SET @mm = DATEDIFF(mm, @FromDt, GETDATE())
    SET @dd = DATEDIFF(dd, @FromDt, GETDATE())
    SET @getmm = ABS(DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, @yy, @FromDt), GETDATE()))
    SET @getdd = ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, @yy, @FromDt), GETDATE()), DATEADD(yy, @yy, @FromDt)), GETDATE()))
    IF @getmm = 1
    set @getmm=0

    RETURN (
      Convert(varchar(10),@yy) + 'y ' + Convert(varchar(10),@getmm) + 'm ')
END
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.  You need some punctuation in your description and your title.  you talk about NULL and yet you're checking `1900-01-01`.  And this UDF clearly doesn't compile/save right now.  I'm just not sure what you want.  Why don't you describe what this UDF is supposed to do.  What do the inputs mean, how are they used, and what should the results be, and what is the current issue that you're having?

Comment: @EliGassert made changes please see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IsNull or Coalesce.  Like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[hmsGetLosText]
   (@FromDt as datetime,@DateLeftOrg as Datetime) 
returns varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @yy AS SMALLINT, @mm AS INT, @dd AS INT,
        @getmm as INT, @getdd as INT, @Fvalue varchar(255)

    --if @DateLeftOrg is null, use GetDate
    SET @DateLeftOrg = CASE WHEN @DateLeftOrg IS NULL THEN GetDate()
       WHEN @DateLeftOrg = '1/1/1900' THEN GetDate()
       ELSE @DateLeftOrg
       END

    SET @yy = DATEDIFF(yy, @FromDt, @DateLeftOrg)
    SET @mm = DATEDIFF(mm, @FromDt, @DateLeftOrg)
    SET @dd = DATEDIFF(dd, @FromDt, @DateLeftOrg)
    SET @getmm = ABS(DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, @yy, @FromDt), @DateLeftOrg))
    SET @getdd = ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, @yy, @FromDt), @DateLeftOrg)), DATEADD(yy, @yy, @FromDt)), @DateLeftOrg))
    IF @getmm = 1
       set @getmm=0

    RETURN (
      Convert(varchar(10),@yy) + 'y ' + Convert(varchar(10),@getmm) + 'm ')
END
```

Comment: will this swap and use getdate if dateleftorg is null then ?

Comment: does this work when the date is 1 1 1900? ie blank date

Comment: This only works for date=null not for 1-1-1900. I will add another line for that. See revisions.

Comment: I take it i dont need to worry about the time stamp in that case then thanks very much helped a great deal thanks

Comment: @ tgolisch i tried it their said the datediff requires three arguments for somereason any idea whats wrong?

Comment: I need to subtract one year form the date if If year in Date Joined is after the Year in Date Left you need to minus one Year.  This is the same for months